# Dependent NSURLConnections

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

In my project i have a service call based on the response we need to pass it to other service call and get the Response and it must be a **Synchronous** call.

We can try in One way where Creating a `NSURLConnection` and having delegate menthos and in `Didfinish` we can do.

Instead of it can we use `NSoperationQueue` and do it, How can we do? Any sample

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSURLSession for it. Just use the NSURLSession block for calling the another service in completion block.